# How to pass FlowRouter context in testing React components

Tags: meteor, reactjs, flow-router, enzyme, mantrajs

I am testing a react component that have 5 links on it. Each link becomes active based on the current route. I am using Meteor with Mantra and enzyme for testing these components.

**Footer component:**

```
import React from 'react';

class Footer extends React.Component{

    render(){
       let route = FlowRouter.current().route.name;

       return(
          <a className={route == 'hub page' ? 'some-class active' : 'some-class'}> . . . (x5)
       )
    }

}
```

**Testing**

```
describe {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Footer from '../core/components/footer';

describe('footer',() => {
    it('should have 5 links', () => {
       const fooWrapper = shallow(<Footer/>);
       expect(fooWrapper.find('a')).to.have.length(5);
    })
})
```

But when I run `npm test`, it says that `FlowRouter is not defined.` How do I pass the FlowRouter context to a react component in testing? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to comply with Mantra specifications, you should rewrite your Footer component like this:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Footer = ({ route }) => (
  <a className={
    route == 'hub page' ? 'some-class active' : 'some-class'
  }> ... (x5)
);

export default footer;
```

Now to test your Footer, you don't now need FlowRouter at all:

```js
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Footer from '../core/components/footer';

describe('footer', () => {
  it('should have 5 links', () => {
    const fooWrapper = shallow(<Footer route={'foo'}/>);
    expect(fooWrapper.find('a')).to.have.length(5);
  })
})
```

To make the footer reactively re-render as `FlowRouter.current()` changes, you need to create a [Mantra container](https://kadirahq.github.io/mantra/#sec-Containers) to wrap it in. To test the container, you can mock FlowRouter like this:

```js
it('should do something', () => {
  const FlowRouter = { current: () => ({ route: { name: 'foo' } }) };

  const container = footerContainer({ FlowRouter }, otherArguments);
  ...
})
```

Since Mantra uses the `mocha` package directly from NPM instead of the `practicalmeteor:mocha` or similar Meteor package to run tests, you cannot (to my knowledge) load Meteor packages such as `kadira:flow-router` in your tests.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I encounter an error, however. It says that `cannot find module meteor/kadira:flow-router` @Waiski

Comment: @Cyval Have you run `meteor add kadira:flow-router`?

Comment: yeah i have. but it doesn't seem to work when I use `import` @Waiski

Comment: @Cyval Sorry, I hadn't realized that Mantra runs test differently to what I've used to, and thus you can't use Meteor packages in your tests. I've now edited the answer accordingly.